# Using default predicate for sort with templates. C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to define the class template as shown below

```
template <typename T> class test{
       std::list<T> container;
       public:
       template <typename type, typename PRED = std::greater<int>>
        void push(type e, PRED comp = std::greater<int>) {
            container.push_back(e);
            container.sort(comp);
        }

};
```

From main I want to be able to tell sort how the sorting should be done. But I also want sort to use std::greater if nothing is specified. The code above is telling me that std::greater is illegal.

Comment: `std::greater` lives in the `functional` header. Did you remember to `#include <functional>` ?

Comment: `std::greater<int>` is the *class* not an instance as needed for the default argument. And since the `PRED` type already is the correct type you could use `PRED()` as the object for the default argument.

Comment: It should be `PRED comp = std::greater<int>{}`.

Comment: And for future questions please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), and try to create a proper [mcve] to show us. And include all the errors you get from building, copy-pasted in full and complete as text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to do this:

```
template <typename type, typename PRED = std::greater<T>>
void push(type e, PRED comp = PRED()) {
    // ...
}
```

Use `std::greater<T>` as the default template argument, so that it will work even when `T` is not `int`.

Use `PRED()` as the default value for the `comp` argument, so that it will work even if the user specifies some other default-constructible predicate type, like `std::less<T>`.

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted. Thought i start of with <int> to make it easy on myself. But I guess I was missing the crucial PRED comp = PRED(). Thank you